# PHP: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in

Tags: php

I pretty much copied this code word for word from a tutorial. I'm not sure what is wrong. I searched the error message and it seems like something isn't closed correctly? But like I said I tripled check and this is how it was written in the tutorial?

What could Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in *_*_ in line 44 mean?? Line 44 is the last line

```
<?php /* Template Name: template */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>





            <div id="sidebar1" class="scolumn fix" style="width:326px;">
                <div class="scolumn-pad">
                    <?php pagelines_template_area('pagelines_sidebar1', 'sidebar1'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>


        <div style="width:560px; float:left; margin-top:50px;" >

                <?php query_posts('category_name=template-category');?>
                 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


                 <div style="float:inherit; padding-bottom:10px;"> 

                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                     <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></small>

                    <span>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
                        </a>

                    </span>
                    <!-- Content -->
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>

                     <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: It probably means there is no line 44.

Comment: ??. Elaboration?
I deleted all blank lines. So line 44 is <?php get_footer(); ?>. I also deleted <?php get_footer(); ?> so that </div> is the last line. Still get the error.

Comment: In your code above there are only 39 lines.

Comment: Thanks, but CornelB's solution worked for me.

Comment: Alternatively remove colon after `if` -> `if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`   BTW this tutorial is a nonsense. `while ( have_posts() )` would be sufficient, `if` is redundant there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
<?php endif ;?>
```

after `endwhile`

Comment: Thanks!!! This worked. I thought I only needed one.

Answer (score 0):

**missing  `;` check and update**

```
 the_permalink()
 the_time('F jS, Y')
 the_permalink()
```

replace it with

```
  the_permalink();
     the_time('F jS, Y');
     the_permalink();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `;` in three function calls

```
<?php the_permalink() ?>
<?php the_author_posts_link() ?>
<?php the_permalink() ?>
```

replace it with

```
<?php the_permalink(); ?>
    <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
    <?php the_permalink(); ?>
```

Comment: That is how the tutorial wrote them.